# Ajax.ActionLink not being recognized as an AjaxRequest in MVC controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have this display box and link on my view, it displays the hours variable and an edit action link and save action link for each item in the model, each are in their own separate form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "WeeklyTarget"))
{
    <td id="hoursEdit">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hours)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Index", "WeeklyTarget",
            new {id = item.WeeklyTargetId},
            new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "hoursEdit", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}) 
        @Html.ActionLink("Save", "SaveChanges", new {weeklytarget = item})
    </td>
}
```

This link takes the id of the row that it is on and it SHOULD (I'm hoping) follow the AjaxRequest logic in the ActionResult below:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    //I'd expect this to evaluate as true
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        var weeklytarget = db.WeeklyTargets.Find(id);
        return PartialView("HoursUpdate", weeklytarget);
    }
    var weeklytargets = db.WeeklyTargets.Include(w => w.User).Include(w => w.Weekly);
    return View(weeklytargets.ToList());
}
```

However when I select this Edit link, the `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` evaluates as false and it jumps past, why is this? I've tried throwing in an `!` to see what would happen if I forced the code to execute but since it's not recognized as an ajax call the `InsertionMode.Replace` won't execute properly and I am left stuck on the partial view page that I was trying to return back to the main page. Why is this not being recognized?

Comment: Do you have the required jQuery scripts included on the page?

Comment: Chcke if you have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js linked.

Comment: I had: `<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` and `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` already included, I now added `<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>` but nothing has changed.

Comment: tryin installing this nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive/. This should add jquery.unobtrusive-ajax library and link it from your page.

Comment: To no avail.. although I didn't have that script before.

Comment: Clear your cache. It's possible the GET request is returning cached results before you included the necessary scripts.